# Is data sent from the server also encrypted in HTTPS/SSL?

Tags: ssl, https

I'm using wireshark and then opening gmail and hotmail to see if I can see the HTML text sent from server to client, but I couldn't find it! Is it encrypted? I knew HTTPS encrypts client packets -- not both!
Please tell me what is wrong with my information.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS is [HTTP over SSL/TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818), where SSL/TLS encrypts the connection in both directions.

During the SSL/TLS handshake, shared keys are negotiated (via the negotiation of a master secret): you get a client write key and a server write key, as described in [the TLS specification (Key Calculation)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346#section-6.3).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In SSL you and the server both have a public and a private key which is used to encrypt/decrypt sent and received data.

Comment: cant a man in the middle attacker fake the client to know the server messages content ? i know we cant fake the certificate sent from server ..but cant we fake the client so we can read the server's data ?

Comment: You would have to have access to the server's public certificate. If you did, then you would be able to view the contents of messages sent from the server to the client. Here is [a paper](http://www.pburkholder.com/sysadmin/SSL-mitm/index.php) regarding the subject.

Comment: that paper is about SSL stripping or misconfiguration client.
and it worked on old IE because of its bad implementation.

but what do u mean with "You would have to have access to the server's public certificate" ? do u mean if i am MITM attacking and got the certificate i can decrypt the message sent from server ?!

Comment: -1, in SSL/TLS, unless you're using client-certificate authentication, only the server has a public/private key pair, and it's not what's used for the encryption anyway.

Comment: In addition, to decipher the traffic, you'd need the server's private key (not its certificate: it's public information) and a cipher suite that doesn't support Perfect Forward Secrecy. The paper you're referring to is about MITM attacks, where a rogue server intercepts the traffic (and where the client doesn't do the required verifications), it's different.